# Adding Missing Dates in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an array that has the past 5 days. It is built like this:

```
(
    "2015-01-27",
    "2015-01-26",
    "2015-01-25",
    "2015-01-24",
    "2015-01-23",
)
```

I have a second NSArray from a FetchRequest

```
(
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-24";
        sumValue = 2500;
    },
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-25";
        sumValue = 1487;
    },
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-27";
        sumValue = 750;
    }
)
```

What I want is the dates that match my first array get a value in the first array, the missing dates get no value.

So the final result will look like this:

```
(
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-23";
        sumValue = 0;
    },
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-24";
        sumValue = 2500;
    },
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-25";
        sumValue = 1000;
    },
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-26";
        sumValue = 0;
    },
    {
        daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-27";
        sumValue = 750;
    }
)
```

Anybody have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to describe the data structure of `2015-01-27 (Value:56)`. What is this object? How do we construct a new one of these objects?

Comment: Thanks Ian. It is from a fetchRequest on a Cora Data Object. It comes with 2 properties. One is an NSString YYYY-MM-DD and the 2nd field is a Float. I retreive it like this:
    NSPropertyDescription *daySectionIdentifierProperty = entity.propertiesByName[@"daySectionIdentifier"];
    
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:daySectionIdentifierProperty,sumExpressionDescription,nil];
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[daySectionIdentifierProperty];

Comment: Can you please update your question with this code, because this is not readable.

Comment: You haven't really told us how to construct a new one, though; that only describes how you retrieve existing instances.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code to get Array 2. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the second array actually contains by the time you want to use it. Can you give an example on that?

Comment: Thanks Adam. The 2nd Array looks like this:

daySectionIdentifier='2015-01-27'
sumValue=46

Comment: Why are you using arrays full of arrays instead of using an NSdictionary? Then you could have a date key and a value key for each entry

Comment: @weesplodge In his example, because executeFetchRequest method returns an array. Certainly, is more suitable to work with NSDictionary as you suggested to solve this... But then he should re-arrange data from result array.

Comment: Thanks weesplodge and Whirlwind. The nsarray is an input for another function. When I send array 1 through it works good, but the function then doesn't display the missing dates. That is why I want to add the missing dates with 0 value so they show up. Can you describe how to do this? I am thinking of cyclying through Array 1 and then comparing the date in Array 2. if it matches I add the value to Array 1. I don't know how to do that. Unless there is a simpler way?

Comment: I simplified the question to its most basic. Take data from one NSArray to another. Anybody know how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this didn't turn out to be too hard, hopefully this is what you are after:

Firstly thinking about the problem, the issue somewhat here is getting the data in the right format to be able to analyse, so first of all I changed it from an array filled with dictionaries to an array of arrays with each array containing the information (I know not the most elegant solution but one that works none the less)

```
// Here is our array of past dates
NSArray * pastDateDays = @[@"2015-01-27", @"2015-01-26", @"2015-01-25", @"2015-01-24", @"2015-01-23"];

// Here is our array from the request, this is full of dictionaries
NSArray * fetchRequest = @[@{@"daySectionIdentifier" : @"2015-01-24", @"sumValue": @2500}, @{@"daySectionIdentifier" : @"2015-01-25", @"sumValue": @1487}, @{@"daySectionIdentifier" : @"2015-01-27", @"sumValue": @750}];

// Here is a mutable array we will be adding to
NSMutableArray * request = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchRequest];
```

So now we are ready to start getting the information into a slightly nicer format.

```
// This function gets the array in an array of arrays where each array has a date and a value
fetchRequest = [self fetchRequestToArray:fetchRequest];

// Not too complicated just taking it out of one and putting it in another
- (NSArray *)fetchRequestToArray: (NSArray *)array {

    NSMutableArray * tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSDictionary * dict in array) {

        NSArray * temp = @[[dict objectForKey:@"daySectionIdentifier"], [dict objectForKey:@"sumValue"]];

        [tempArray addObject:temp];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
}
```

Next we loop through a mutable array of the dates in our date array and if they match in our requested array we remove them:

```
NSMutableArray * tempDates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:pastDateDays];

for (NSArray * array in fetchRequest) {

    NSString * date = array.firstObject;

    for (NSString * string in pastDateDays) {

        if ([date isEqualToString:string]) {

            [tempDates removeObject:string];
        }
    }
}
```

This leaves us with an array of dates which are included in our date array but are not included in our requested data. These are the dates we need to add a zero value for.

Again this is relatively simple:

```
for (NSString * date in tempDates) {

    NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[date, @0]
                                                           forKeys:@[@"daySectionIdentifier", @"sumValue"]];

    [request addObject:dict];
}
```

This returns us with the desired array.

The only thing that might need to be added is that this array isn't in date order. This can be easily sorted with a number of methods. I found and added this on in a few seconds but you could choose a more complicated one if you need it:

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"daySectionIdentifier"
                                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDate];
NSArray * sortedArray = [request sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

This will output the date in the format:

The final array is the array called request and is a mutableArray

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fade848f480>(
{
    daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-23";
    sumValue = 0;
},
{
    daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-24";
    sumValue = 2500;
},
{
    daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-25";
    sumValue = 1487;
},
{
    daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-26";
    sumValue = 0;
},
{
    daySectionIdentifier = "2015-01-27";
    sumValue = 750;
}
)
```

Which I think is the desired output.

Things to note: 
 - The values are NSNumbers and not integers as we can't store integers in an NSdictionary

- This is not the most elegant solution - I have used a lot of arrays and i am sure it could be refactored. This code though does work and so can be worked with to build understanding - this code should work when copied straight in but there may be a few things needing tweaking as it is a long answer copied from my XCode
- The strings need to be in exactly this format for it to work, if they are not then this solution will need to be tweaked.

I hope this helps

Comment: You are the man. Thank you very much weesplodge. Everything works perfectly. Really it is appreciated. Thanks again. I will have to up vote you when I get enough reputation points.